# Merge array of objects by key/value

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I am trying to figure out the best way to map an objects id property that is within a multi-dimension array to object values that are within another array that share the same id.

As an example i have an array of genre_ids like so:

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'sci-fi'},
1: {id: 2, name 'comedy'},
2: {id: 3, name: 'action'}
```

And an array of tv_show_genre_ids which looks like:

```
0: {name: ..., genre_ids: [1, 4, 9]},
1: {name: ..., genre_ids: [2, 3, 4]},
```

I was trying to figure out the best way to retrieve a list of the genres name by its id.

I have managed to create a working solution so far but it feels incredibly dirty as i am performing multiple nested loops and i wasn't sure if there is a cleaner more declarative approach to my solution

Here is my approach which assumes i already have a list of genre ids and names (accessed within `this.genres`.

```
this.http.get('https://api.com/shows')
    .subscribe((res: array <any> ) => {
        this.shows = res.results;
        this.shows.forEach(show => {
            show.genre_names = '';
            show.genre_ids.forEach(id => {
                for (const [i, v] of this.genres.entries()) {
                    if (id == v.id) {
                        if (this.genres[i] && this.genres[i].name) {
                            if (show.genre_names === '') {
                                show.genre_names = this.genres[i].name
                            } else {
                                show.genre_names += `, ${this.genres[i].name}`;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Is there a better way of doing this as i seem to come across this type of problem quite often when trying to map ids from one object to another within multi-dimension arrays.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the Genre Data from the API af:

```
 0: {id: 10759, name: "Action & Adventure"}
 1: {id: 16, name: "Animation"}
```

And here is an example of the show data from the API:

```
0:
backdrop_path: "/ok1YiumqOCYzUmuTktnupOQOvV5.jpg"
first_air_date: "2004-05-10"
genre_ids: (2) [16, 35]
id: 100
name: "I Am Not an Animal"
origin_country: ["GB"]
original_language: "en"
original_name: "I Am Not an Animal"
overview: "I Am Not An Animal is an animated comedy series about the only six talking animals in the world, whose cosseted existence in a vivisection unit is turned upside down when they are liberated by animal rights activists."
popularity: 10.709
poster_path: "/nMhv6jG5dtLdW7rgguYWvpbk0YN.jpg"
vote_average: 9.5
vote_count: 341
```

I want to add a new property to the show object named genre_names which gets the genre name via the genre response.

Comment: Given the two inputs "genre_ids" and "tv_show_genre_ids", what is the expected output? I think this will help understand the problem better.

Comment: Well every show object has a property which contains an array of genre ids. I want each of the values within that array to map to the value in the genre list array that i already have and then add a new property to each individual show with all of the genre names that are applicable to it. If that makes sense?

You can see the new property that i have created 'show.genre_names'. I would like this to contain all of the genre names but i need to get the name of the genre by its ID which is in another array.

Comment: I mean, can you give the actual output? Not the the explanation. What will it be like if you console log the output, for a sample input?

Comment: I have made an edit to the original post. I hope this is what you was asking for in regards to the input. Sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to first convert your genres into a `Map` or an object to use as a lookup:

```
const genreLookup = new Map();
this.genres.forEach(genre => genreLookup.set(genre.id, genre));
```

Now when you process an array of shows, you don't have to loop through the genres multiple times:

```
this.shows.forEach(show => {
  show.genre_names = show.genre_ids
    .filter(id => genreLookup.has(id))
    .map(id => genreLookup.get(id).name)
    .join(', ');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems significantly cleaner :-)